# Displaying A Pdf Document

Tags: jakarta-ee

**How to Display a pdf document in a web page(Not seprately,just Inside the webpage) using jsp or servlet?**

Comment: Isn't that normally a thing the browser decide about?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<object>` or `<embed>` tag to contain the adobe reader and point to your pdf file.

something like: `<embed src="YourFile.pdf" width="500" height="375">`

another answer here: [EMBED vs. OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type for this on response.
call response.setContentType("aplication/pdf"); before writing anything to stream.

Comment: See Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968328/question-on-java-servlet-to-open-a-pdf-file-using-itext) or [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040776/i-cant-open-a-pdf-in-my-browser-by-java)